# What is the practical lesson on this side of the Korach story?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, parshat-korach

It is often said that the Torah is not a history book, and is very selective in which events and lessons it relates, such that they are relevant to all generations.

The story of Korach seems to be teaching us a timeless story, in that an unfalsifiable set of allegations are made against a person or group by a corrupt individual, that are nonetheless quite persuasive and end up causing a lot of damage. This is the type of thing that happens a lot in life, especially in anything political (and very much today as ever!)

I understand that there are many timeless lessons given in the commentaries from this event, but one thing that this event does not obviously help us with, is how to resolve it, because in that case it was resolved through the accused asking God to falsify the unfalsifiable by performing a miracle, and removing them at the same time:

> וְאִם־בְּרִיאָה יִבְרָא יְהֹוָה וּפָצְתָה הָאֲדָמָה אֶת־פִּיהָ
> וּבָלְעָה אֹתָם וְאֶת־כׇּל־אֲשֶׁר לָהֶם וְיָרְדוּ חַיִּים שְׁאֹלָה
> וִידַעְתֶּם כִּי נִאֲצוּ הָאֲנָשִׁים הָאֵלֶּה אֶת־יְהֹוָה׃
>
> But if the Lord creates a new thing, and the earth opens her mouth,
> and swallows them up, with all that appertain to them, and they go
> down alive into She᾽ol; then you shall understand that these men have
> provoked the Lord.
>
> וַיְהִי כְּכַלֹּתוֹ לְדַבֵּר אֵת כׇּל־הַדְּבָרִים הָאֵלֶּה וַתִּבָּקַע
> הָאֲדָמָה אֲשֶׁר תַּחְתֵּיהֶם׃
>
> And it came to pass, as he had made an end of speaking all these
> words, that the ground split beneath them

([Bamidbar 16:30-31](https://www.sefaria.org/Numbers.16.30?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)).

Has anyone seen any explanations from Torah sources that are able to draw a practical lesson **specifically on how to deal with situations of Korachs or anti-Korachs** (i.e. when the person making the unfalsifiable claim is actually right, and the accused is corrupt) **in times when we don't generally presume we can ask Hashem to give a sign who is right and remove the corrupt party on our behalf?**

Comment: Rabbi Jonathan Sacks: "The flagrant falsehoods [antisemites] sometimes utter – that Israel was not the birthplace of the Jewish people, that there never was a Temple in Jerusalem, that Israel is a “colonial” power, a foreign transplant alien to the Middle East – rival the claims of Dathan and Aviram that Egypt was a land flowing with milk and honey and that Moses brought the people out solely in order to kill them in the desert. Why bother with truth when all that matters is power? Thus the spirit of Korach lives on."  I add: We just have to learn to live with Korach.

Comment: I like the question, but it doesn't sound too promising, does it? It sounds like it's hard to deal with demagogues effectively, and people are very suggestible.

Comment: Moshe is saying, "Hashem, do not be *mepharnes* this person from Your *briah*. Korach created his own world, so let him be *mepharnes* it himself." With the inevitable consequences described in your question, which I think, also answers your question.

Comment: @TheGRAPKE please spell it out for me, and let me know if I have it wrong: are you saying that the solution to Korach is to basically trust (in Hashem? In reality?) that these people "dig their own grave"? How does this look in practice? BTW if you read Zohar, I think this is relevant to your point: https://www.sefaria.org/Zohar%2C_Bereshit.6.48

Comment: Maybe there is still a practical lesson to be learned on how to deal with situations of Korachs in times when we don't generally presume we can ask Hashem to remove the corrupt party on our behalf: "וידבר אל־העדה לאמר סורו נא מעל אהלי האנשים הרשעים האלה ואל־תגעו בכל־אשר להם פן־תספו בכל־חטאתם" ([Bamidbar 16:26](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Numbers.16.26?lang=bi&lang2=en), "He addressed the community, saying, 'Move away from the tents of these wicked men and touch nothing that belongs to them, lest you be wiped out for all their sins.'"). And, they did that (in v.27), _before_ being given a sign.

Comment: @RabbiKaii "Are you saying that the solution to Korach is to basically trust (in Hashem? In reality?) that these people "dig their own grave"?" You have to *steig aus* out of their sphere of influence, there is no choice, and yes, to do that you need *bitachon*. "How does this look in practice." That can look like an entire lifetime of trusting that if you do the right thing, then Hashem will make sure that the right thing will happen.